# Most efficient/aesthetic 3 way boolean check in C#

Tags: c#, performance, aesthetics

I have a C# function that is updating a database and need to check to make sure two values in a datarow are not null. I know that **ValueA** has a value more often than **ValueB**, so I have a check as follows to make sure I have the most efficient execution (note, using IsNull as a function to check both C# nulls and DBNull.Value):

```
var value= DataRow["ValueA"];
        if (IsNull(value))
        {
            value= DataRow["ValueB"];
            if (IsNull(value))
            {
                _log.LogError("Error occured while attempting to update a table...");
                return;
            }
        }
```

Can anyone see a more efficient way to test whether both are null? Is there any way to reduce the number of lines of code but maintain the efficiency?

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately you are making 2 null checks, regardless of the order you do them or how pretty your code is. When this is interpreted into IL the compiler will simplify this anyway, but in terms of humanly readable code this is fine. An alternative might be to not malloc `value` to two different values and null check the values directly like:

```
if(IsNull(DataRow["ValueA"]) || IsNull(DataRow["ValueB"])
{
    _log.LogError("Error occured while attempting to update a table...");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C# 7 or above you can use the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator), like so:

```
var value = DataRow["ValueA"] ?? DataRow["ValueB"] ?? throw new Exception("Error occured while attempting to update a table...");
```

Combined with a `Try...Catch` to catch the exception.

If the values involved are in fact `DBNull` rather than actual `null`, then you could do this instead (assuming they're `int?`s):

```
var value = DataRow["ValueA"] as int? ?? DataRow["ValueB"] as int? ?? throw new Exception("Error occured while attempting to update a table...");
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about the null coalescing operator.

Comment: The "throw new Exception" seems to be an invalid expression. I'm getting an error after the 2nd null operator and the compiler complains about unreachable code directly after the expression.

Comment: What version of C# are you using? Using throws on the right-hand side of the null  coalescing operator like that was introduced in C# 7.

Comment: `DataRow["ValueA"]` is probably not returning `null` but `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: Updated to handle DBNull as well

Comment: @TheodorZoulias correct, hence my "IsNull" function. Sorry, I should have specified that.

Comment: @Diado Yeah, the version I'm using is probably C# 6. Not sure I'll be able to make use of that particular feature.

Comment: Ah well, I'll leave it here for people using more recent versions :-)